# docker build and publish pull from private repo fails

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have a jenkins job and we build our docker containers using the docker build and publish plugin.

Most of the containers are built and published to our private repos in dockerhub without any issues. They inherit images from public repositories and work fine.

However we have noticed that dockerfiles that contains

> FROM private_repo:tag

fail because docker cannot find the image in our private repo. We have provided credentials via the docker registry credentials option but doesn't work. It simply says

> "image not found"

at the end of the build.

If I login to our jenkins server and do docker login and then pull the image that works fine. This leads me to believe something is wrong with the credentials when it is pulling from the private repo. Has anyone encountered this or know the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have always run `docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD` at the beginning of my docker build / docker push Jenkins jobs.  Save the username/password as a Jenkins credential and you won't have to share it anywhere.

Comment: Though I have never used that plugin (just re-read your question) so I do not know the answer.  Sorry!

Comment: We have saved the credentials as jenkins credential and refer to it in the plugin. However it doesn't seem to make a difference. By the way, how do you add e-mail address in the jenkins credential? There is only username and password.

Comment: Like I said, I have never used the docker build/publish plugin, I just use a shell script to run the commands.

Comment: I am leaning towards using a shell script as well.